# Linux - Routing issue

Tags: linux, rhel, ip, routing

I have multiple computeurs with 3 interfaces in multiple subnet.

For example : (all /24)

```
RED (linux)
eth0 192.22.184.100
eth1 192.23.184.100
eth2 192.24.184.100

BLUE (windows)
nic1 192.22.184.28
nic2 192.23.184.28
nic3 192.24.184.28

CYAN (windows)
nic1 192.22.184.30
nic2 192.20.184.30
```

I had routing problems when I specified a simple gateway on windows machines: the ping to the interface having the gateway worked, but not to the other interfaces.
So, I made that :

[image]

With that, each BLUE's nic can ping each CYAN's nic.

But Linux is a problem.
When I define a gateway, only the interface with it answer to the ping.

When I try to do the same configuration as windows :

[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: I think you would be far better off removing all those routes and setup a routing protocol such as `quagga`'s `ospf`.

Comment: I don't have any router... I use a simple hub + Windows Server with routing feature enabled. My Windows Server has a network card in each subnet (.1).

Comment: It makes no sense to have more than one default route (at the same metric, in the same network namespace). The default route is, by definition, the route to be used for traffic _when no other route exists_. You should have at most one default route; anything more is erroneous.

Comment: @Cassandra I never said router, I said routing protocols. Given you are running windows, I would suggest RIP or RIPv2 on each of the systems.

Comment: @roaima I agree, but with a gateway in my linux (RED), the server answer only for pings to the nic with the gateway. Others nic don't respond...

Comment: @Bib I tried RIP on the Windows, it's OK but Linux is still the problem :(

Comment: You need RIP on all the systems and you need to delete all those routes you applied.

Comment: How can I do it with RedHat 6 ?

Comment: there should be no need to specify routing among same network. I assumed you have checked physical connectivty, regarding hub, wire and so on.  also runing `arp -n` (on linux) and `arp -av` (on windows), did you see other hosts ? using any scan tools on windows, will you detect linux hosts on 192.(23 or 24).184.100 ?

Comment: I can only see the interfaces that I can ping.